# What kind of graphs are the single bonded hydrocarbons considered to be?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, graph-theory

I trying to describe branched, cyclic and chiral molecules.

In case I ignore stereoisomers I can take graphs with nodes of degree less than 5.

Taking stereoisomers into account gets a little trickier. I think I would need a "3D"-graph where each node is ONLY of degree 4 (carbons) AND 1 (hydrogen).

Is there a mathematical concept defining three dimensional graphs?

Or is there any other way to define all the single bonded hydrocarbons?

What definition would you propose to define all the saturated hydrocarbons?

Comment: Can't you use an ordered graph ordering bonds using IUPAC conventions?

Comment: @N74 - What definition would you give exactly? I am not very good in graph theory and have little idea on how to use ordered graphs

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of separate issues here:

1. You can model the connectivity of hydrocarbons with just simple graphs.
2. Chirality (R/S) can be modelled with just vertex labels.
3. 3D layout can describe the chirality, but is not necessary.

For example, the SMILES of a simple structure is essentially just the graph, so for e.g. cis-1,2-Dimethylcyclopropane you can have **C1[C@@H](C)[C@@H]1C** where the chiral carbons are annotated with @@.

Alternatively, the InChI for the trans isomer is **InChI=1S/C5H10/c1-4-3-5(4)2/h4-5H,3H2,1-2H3/t4-,5-/m0/s1** (see [the docs](http://www.inchi-trust.org/technical-faq/#8)) where the /t4-,5-/ layer has the tetrahedral chirality.

There is a lot of information in this link:

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/40809/4665

Comment: Ok, so how would you define saturated hydrocarbons using graphs (not 3D graph)?

Comment: @user1118686 - Just as simple graphs. The only detail would be whether to have hydrogens as implicit or not. Depends what you want to do, really.

Comment: I meant, what would be the full definition that you would give to define hydrocarbons